# Can we acces a UIStackView's subview's size?

Tags: swift, uistackview

My question is pretty simple but I haven't found any answer yet.

I am making a sort of table using two vertical stacks inside a horizontal stack. Both vStacks have different objects (Button in my case, with border for each one) but in the same quantity (so that they are horizontally paired like in a classic table).
I have set both of my vStack's distribution to `.fillProportionally`, and therefore each button have different size depending on their titleLabel length.

However, I would like to make each of my button have the same size of its paired button (the one next to him horizontally, in the other vStack) so that my cells borders would be aligned (using the biggest button's size as a reference in each pair).

I think it involves to find a way to access one stack's subview's size and then constraint the other stack subview to be equally sized. Or, because usually there is only one big button messing with the distribution and offsetting button pairs' border, accessing the way one stack displays its subviews and forcing the other stack to adopt the same way. Either way, I don't know how to do it yet.

I'd be glad if you could help me or lead me to the answer !

(I don't think I need to put code to explain my problem as it's a relatively abstract issue but if you need it I can share it)

EDIT :

[image: Left : What I want, right : What I get]

Left : What I want, right : What I get

Each cell is a button (useless here but in my app it will have a functionality) with border , I want to set "description" button's height equal as "text" button. I hope it's clearer now :) I tried to invert the layout (two horizontal stacks in one vertical stack) but the issue is still here, with width instead of height this time.

EDIT 2 :

Following your advice, here is some code :

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var bottomButton: UIButton!


@IBOutlet weak var vstack: UIStackView!

@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isEnabled = true
    print(sender.frame)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    
    let button = newButton(text: "name")
    let button2 = newButton(text: "John Smith")
    let button3 = newButton(text: "Description")
    let button4 = newButton(text: "text text text text text text text text text text text \n text text text text text \n text text text text text")
    
    let hStack = UIStackView()
    hStack.axis = .horizontal
    hStack.distribution = .fillEqually
    
    let hStack2 = UIStackView()
    hStack2.axis = .horizontal
    hStack2.distribution = .fillEqually
    
    hStack.addArrangedSubview(button)
    hStack.addArrangedSubview(button2)

    hStack2.addArrangedSubview(button3)
    hStack2.addArrangedSubview(button4)

    vstack.addArrangedSubview(hStack)
    vstack.addArrangedSubview(hStack2)
    
}
}

 
func newButton(text: String) -> UIButton {

    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.isEnabled = true
    button.setTitle(text, for: .disabled)
    button.setTitle(text, for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .disabled)
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1
    button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center

    return button
}
```

`

Using horizontal stacks in a vertical stack and Fill Equally partially solves the problem, because it only works when my text is under a certain length, otherwise it clips (see following image), which is why I was using fillProportionally.

[image]

Comment: It sounds like a normal table view, with no need for stack views. Or invert the layout and use several horizontal stack views inside one vertical stack view.

Comment: Yes I thought of inverting the layout but I would waste lot of time rewriting all of the data going inside my table.. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: @Prunsse - your description is a little confusing. Do you want all subviews (buttons, in this case) to be equal widths, matching the widest one? Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0A9e.png ?

Comment: @DonMag I want every button in the same row to be equal width and height. But rows can be of different height.

Comment: @Prunsse - How are you determining the "row heights"? Does your horizontal stack view have a constrained width and / or height? I think you need to add a picture of what you're trying to get, because it's still not quite clear.

Comment: @DonMag - I've edited my post, I hope it's clearer. hStack has no constraint, its .distribution is .fillEqually (to make sure columns' width are equal). Vertical Stacks have no constraint, there .distribution are both .fillProportionally. I want to update any button's frame with a frame equal to its neighbor (in the row) depending who is the biggest. The main issue is that I don't know how to update a view frame after it's been loaded. My current lead is to override view.layoutSubviews().

Comment: As I said before, the thing you are trying to attain (on the left) is easy if you do it the right way: two horizontal stack views inside one vertical stack view. You have basically said (in your comment) that you _don't_ want to do it the right way, you think that's silly, and you insist on doing it in a totally wrong way that isn't working: two vertical stack views inside one horizontal stack view. This sort of reluctance to back out of a dead end and open the door which is waiting unlocked right behind you does not make for a good programming experience.

Comment: @matt - Let's put aside your very kind way of saying things, I just want to mention that I've written this in my edit : " I tried to invert the layout (two horizontal stacks in one vertical stack) but the issue is still here, with width instead of height this time." to notify that I have tried your advice, and it unfortunately created a similar issue. Seems like I'm not that narrow-minded :)
Also, it could be useful in other context to know how to modify a view's frame, developing my knowledge and thus improving programming experience.

Comment: All I'm saying is, if you remove the restriction "do not answer in the following way" and permit the possibility of answering in that way, I (or someone) will be glad to show you how to achieve the layout shown on the left in your diagram.

Comment: @Prunsse - with the example you posted, it's incredibly simple to do... a vertical stack view, with two "row" horizontal stack views, with Distribution: Fill Equally. So, a couple tips: 1) remove `.fillProportionally` from your vocabulary - it's the most misunderstood Distribution, and almost certainly not what you want. 2) Include in your question a ***REAL*** example, with ***REAL*** strings / objects you're trying to arrange.

Comment: Sorry I was trying to simplify my issue by generalizing too much which was unproductive but I've added some code to my post and an image showing why 2 horizontals in a vertical stack is not yet working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - part of the problem is that you are modifying the `titleLabel` properties -- specifically, setting its `.numberOfLines = 0`. Auto-layout does ***not*** take that into account, without a little help.

You'll want to use a button subclass, such as this:

```
class MultiLineButton: UIButton {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        // if you want to give your buttons some "padding" around the title
        //contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8.0, left: 8.0, bottom: 8.0, right: 8.0)
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        guard let tl = titleLabel else {
            return .zero
        }
        let size = tl.intrinsicContentSize
        return CGSize(width: size.width + contentEdgeInsets.left + contentEdgeInsets.right, height: size.height + contentEdgeInsets.top + contentEdgeInsets.bottom)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        guard let tl = titleLabel else { return }
        tl.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = tl.frame.size.width
    }

}
```

Using that class, here is an example view controller where we add a vertical stack view, and 2 horizontal "row" stack views:

```
class PruViewController: UIViewController {

    func newButton(text: String) -> MultiLineButton {
        let b = MultiLineButton()
        b.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)
        b.setTitle(text, for: [])
        b.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        b.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
        b.setTitleColor(.black, for: .disabled)
        b.layer.borderWidth = 1
        b.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        return b
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let button = newButton(text: "name")
        let button2 = newButton(text: "John Smith")
        let button3 = newButton(text: "Description")
        let button4 = newButton(text: "text text text text text text text text text text text \n text text text text text \n text text text text text")
        
        let vStack = UIStackView()
        vStack.axis = .vertical
        vStack.distribution = .fill
        
        let hStack = UIStackView()
        hStack.axis = .horizontal
        hStack.distribution = .fillEqually
        
        let hStack2 = UIStackView()
        hStack2.axis = .horizontal
        hStack2.distribution = .fillEqually
        
        hStack.addArrangedSubview(button)
        hStack.addArrangedSubview(button2)
        
        hStack2.addArrangedSubview(button3)
        hStack2.addArrangedSubview(button4)
        
        vStack.addArrangedSubview(hStack)
        vStack.addArrangedSubview(hStack2)
        
        vStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(vStack)
        
        // respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            vStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            vStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            vStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        ])
        
    }
}
```

The result:

[image]

And, you'll notice in my `MultiLineButton` class a comment about adding "padding" around the button title labels... here's how it looks with that line un-commented:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to answer my question, it's a perfectly working solution and I will definitely go with, but I'll need to have a deeper look into it to fully understand everything that you've done, some notions are still a bit unclear to me. But at least I can move on, thank you very much !